# Is there an objective standard of what constitutes an advanced Force maneuver?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

In a comment on [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/135087/69120), I said that I don't know what constitutes an advanced Force maneuver, and that claiming any one maneuver to be advanced seems like conjecture and speculation.

Is there an objective standard of what constitutes an advanced Force maneuver?

Disney canon preferred, Legends will do if there's nothing in canon.

Comment: If this isn't already on your xmas list, it should be. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book)

Comment: There will be nothing in canon because there's no such thing as a "Force maneuver" in Disney canon.

Comment: The problem is that "advanced" is very subjective.  Advanced for Yoda is a lot different than advanced for a Youngling.  Is there a frame of reference in which your friend (from the other question) that can be used to establish some sort of baseline for what advanced is

Comment: @psubsee2003 Sorry, but he didn't give a baseline. He simply said a mind trick is advanced, without comparing it to anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming we take the reference book "[The Jedi Path - A Manual for Students of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book))" as an *objective source*, we've got a pretty good idea what force abilities are considered to be basic and which are considered more advanced.

### Initiate skills

> USING CONTROL ABILITIES
>
> As Jedi Initiates, you will learn and hone many abilities that draw
>   upon the Force. These abilities follow three themes: Control, Sense,
>   and Alter. Control is centered on one’s own body and is the focus of
>   training for Initiates. If you cannot remain in control of yourself,
>   you will never be able to extend the Force and command your
>   surrounding environment. **Sense and Alter abilities will be the focus
>   of your training later, when you are more skilled.**

Initiate level '*Control*' abilities include the ability to heal oneself, to absorb energy from the environment and to attain a state of Force meditation.

### Padawan / Knight level skills

More advanced versions of these 'control' abilities include the famed Jedi "Hibernation Trance", the ability to defend oneself from drugs and poisons, the ability to reduce the perception of pain, the ability to deflect harmful energy and the ability to heal oneself from the effects of ageing.

As one becomes more advanced, you can also add ***Sense*** and ***Alter*** techniques to your repertoire. *Sense* abilities include the power to detect life, to detect other Force users, to sense and be guided by the will of the Living Force, precognition and certain forms of telepathy. *Alter* abilities include telekinesis, mind-control and the control of animals and certain plants.

### Supreme mastery

The very most powerful Jedi can absorb force-lightning, block blaster fire and even transcend death.

[image]

Comment: I need to ask.  Is that image actually from one of the countless remasters or is it just a joke image?

Comment: I have not seen the films. Who is that guy at the middle, behind Yoda?

Comment: Okay, thanks! I was specifically thinking of a mind trick, so that would be a padawan-level skill.  @Oriol It's Qui-Gon Jinn from Episode I.